# Django Select2 Line-height choices

Tags: django-forms, django-select2

I would like to make the line-height for the dropdown choices of this Select2 results smaller. (See image) I can't find what css to use. Looked in the Select2 package but could not find something that worked[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj0hD.png). Anyone who knows?

Tried: .select2-choices .select2-results
ul li.select2-selection__choice,
ul li.select2-search {
line-height: 10px
}